# Android studio shuts down after opening XML file

Tags: android-studio

I have a problem with adroid studio:

- It shuts down everytime I open tab with .xml file (both when I open
  it in text or design mode)
- It works perfectly when i'm working on .java tabs
- I noticed it today, I've not been working on xml for 2 days, and 2
  days ago everything was just fine. Also didn't make any updates since then.
- Updated everything there was to update now, still crashes.
- Reboot does not help :D
- It just shuts down. Without any windows crash info or anything.
- I made sure that I have enough space on my disc C, so it's rather not
  any space/memory issue.
- Windows 7, 64bit

Any help would be very nice. Can I find some logs about crashes? If yes could you tell me where so I could paste them here?

**EDIT: Solved by running Files -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.**
I guess I'll leave this post here in case someone google it in the future.

Comment: I am facing same issue with my Android Studio project. Tried with your solution but it doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for more than 2 month. Tried everythig

- Clean and re-build project
- Invalidate cashes
- Re-installing Android Studio
- Re-installing Windows
- Even installing Linux did not help.

None of this helped till new BumbleBee release of Android Studio came out. Now it works well.

So, the only solution from my side - upgrade Android Studio to BumbleBee version.

I've also noticed that these crashes started when I first upgraded to FireFox release. So, I do not recommend it.